# How to find which of the items are modified in a list when we work on client side and send it to server side in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, collections, soa

I am working on SOA based project and i got got a situation where I am sending the whole array of object to server and then I have to see which of the objects are new and which one I have to update, hence I am looking for some generic function which can get me the list with update , delete or insert attribute

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem where I was sending entity with multiple children entities. The challenge was to figure out what child entity has been updated, added or deleted. Here what I did.

1. Implemented `IObjectWithState` with `ChildEntity`. (Inspired from one of pluralsight entityframework video)
2. Pull the server side version of entity.
3. Invoked `FindDifference` to get the difference of Child entities on client and server

```
IList<ClassTicket> clientSideTickets = /// What received from client
IList<ClassTicket> serverSideTickets = /// What received from database


  var diffTickets = FindDifference(clientSideTickets ,serverSideTickets ,
    (ticket1, ticket2) => ticket1.Id == ticket2.Id,(ticket1, ticket2) => ticket1.Name == ticket2.Name && ticket1.NoOfTicketsAvailable == ticket2.NoOfTicketsAvailable && ticket1.Price == ticket2.Price);

public interface IObjectWithState
{
    State State { get; set; }
}


// My Child Entity
public class ClassTicket: IObjectWithState
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public short NoOfTicketsAvailable { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}


public static IEnumerable<T> FindDifference<T>(IEnumerable<T> clientList, IEnumerable<T> serverList, Func<T, T, bool> identityDetector, Func<T, T, bool> changeDetector) where T : IObjectWithState
{
    var finalList = new List<T>();
    var clientItems = clientList as T[] ?? clientList.ToArray();
    var serverItems = serverList as T[] ?? serverList.ToArray();
    foreach (var clientItem in clientItems)
    {
        bool foundInServerList = false;
        foreach (var serverItem in serverItems)
        {
            if(identityDetector(clientItem, serverItem))
            {
                foundInServerList = true;
                clientItem.State = !changeDetector(clientItem, serverItem) ? State.Modified : State.Unchanged;
                finalList.Add(clientItem);
                break;
            }
        }
            if(!foundInServerList)
            {
                clientItem.State = State.Added;
                finalList.Add(clientItem);
            }
        }


foreach (var serverItem in serverItems)
{
    var foundInClientList = clientItems.Any(clientItem => identityDetector(serverItem, clientItem));
    if (!foundInClientList)
    {
        serverItem.State = State.Deleted;
        finalList.Add(serverItem);
    }
}
    return finalList;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help, but i will really appreciate if you format the code that might help a lot.

Comment: Thanks acdcjuniour. I guess you formatted code. I did my best but could not format.